How to get rid of old files originating from previously deleted projects in Eclipse's history?
In one of my Eclipse workspaces, I have a significant size of local history (I mean the total size of files under workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history), exceeding 1.5 GB. Upon checking the contents of the directory, I discovered numerous versions of rather large text files, 5 - 10 MB each, which were part of a project I worked on about a year ago.
At that time, I needed the local history of those files, so I intentionally configured the local history settings with very large values. After completing the work, I deleted the project and returned the local history settings to more reasonable values, expecting Eclipse to clear the local history. However, Eclipse did not remove the files from the local history, and I'm unsure why.
I'd like to get rid of those large files. Is there a way to force Eclipse to remove them? If not, can I simply delete those files manually? Additionally, I'm interested in knowing where and how Eclipse stores an index of the files in the local history. If I knew this, perhaps I could make a simple tool to automate the cleanup process.

Did you delete the project with or without the option Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)? If you did delete it without the option, does creating a project with the same name and then deleting it with the option help?

@howlger Yes, with this option.

Those are your previous history files when you want to restore from previous history or local history while editing.  You can remove them but then will not have a previous history for that particular file.  You can configure that history using the following path:
Window->preferences->workspace->local history
The window looks something like the following:

To apply the changes you need to go to Windows->Preferences->General->Startup and shutdown.  At the top, check Refresh workspace on startup
Unfortunately, I do not know the mappings Eclipse uses to tie all the files and supporting directories together.

Yes, I have already configured these settings, but Eclipse did not remove the old files after that. However, it appears from your answer that these files can be safely deleted manually. This is the main thing I wanted to know, thank you. Still I won't mark your answer as accepted for a while, hoping that somebody who knows the mapping will provide some information about it.

@m.vokhm  Windows->Preferences->General->Startup and shutdown  At the top, checking Refresh workspace on startup seemed to do it for me.

Yes. Usually this works for me too, but this time something obviously went wrong. May be some Eclipse bug or a system glitch

@m.vokhm you may want to checkout http://bugs.eclipse.org.

@m.vokhm  And I am using the following:    (includes Incubating components) Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0) Build id: 20240307-1437 OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32 Java vendor: Oracle Corporation Java runtime version: 21.0.1+12-LTS-29 Java version: 21.0.1
